# Visual Studio 2010: Is it possible to syntax highlight all "==" outside of conditions?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just spent hours trying to debug my code.  The whole problem boiled down to a line:

a == b;

when I really wanted

a = b;

A classic and foolish problem.  The thing is, my eyes just glossed over == every time I checked this section of code.

Is there a way to enable a syntax highlighting (squiggles) on all == outside of conditionals?

That is, I want Visual Studio to warn me when I have an == outside of an if(), while(), for(), ?:, etc.  This program was in C++, but I would like the same feature for C# editing.

I'd settle for something that would let me (easily) set error squiggles using regex.

Comment: You don't need it for C#. The language prohibits that.

Comment: Reminds me of the time I wasted a day tracking down a bug that turned out to be a line written `x!=x;`, when the author meant `x=!x;`.  I had probably looked at that line 100 times before I noticed the problem.  It would be nice if more programmers took advantage of their spacebars to make code readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't actually answer your question, but the question seems moot given that the compiler should have given a level 1 warning for that: [C4553](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e11e1wz2.aspx)

Comment: This is good to know for when I'm working on my own projects, but this project is for work, and our build script outputs lots of warnings in a manner that isn't easy to search.  So basically, I lose this nice warning.

Comment: Warnings are good things - they come for free.  Explicitly disable just those that you don't care about.  Fix the rest.

Comment: I'm not denying that warnings are nice. I love warnings when people have dealt with them.  The thing is, the project I'm working on has been around for ~20 years, and not everyone has cleaned up their code (or maybe it was considered clean when the wrote it).

Additionally, the project takes 6+ minutes to compile, so I'd rather get this warning up front instead of compiling, waiting 6 minutes, fixing a small change, and then waiting another 6 minutes.

Comment: We can go back and forth on the utility of heeding warnings, but seems like your question backs the advice that warnings should be acted on.  Fixing bugs that are called out by warnings saves huge amounts of time.  6 minutes is laughable.  How much time was spent trying to find the problem that prompted you to ask the current question?  I see it in the question: "hours."

Comment: If you're dealing with code that has never been cleaned up, deal with warnings one level at a time.  Compile with warnings set to level 1.  Deal with those results.  Increment level and repeat.  Also, to help partition the work, you only need to compile one file at a time and no need to link.  Warnings in header files multiply since the warning will be repeated in every source file included by the header.  Use warning pragmas to disable those warnings that you really don't care about.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that as a temporary solution, but I still wish Visual Studio would immediately tell me that I'm being stupid.

Comment: Compiler error red squiggles were only introduced in VS2010.  Maybe in the next version, we'll get warning squiggles too.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's useful for `operator==` to be used outside conditionals. Consider:

```
bool valuesAreGood = (a == b) && (c == d) && (a < c) ...;
if (valuesAreGood) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I know that it's useful sometimes, but I would much rather have a warning.